# What R command to use to force download files from iCloud

Tags: r, macos, icloud

On a mac using iCloud file optimization, large files that are seldom used are uploaded to iCloud and only a small pointer file is left. When I look for the file in Finder, I see the file name and to the left is an icon that indicates that the file is in the cloud. To access the file, I click on the icon and the file is downloaded. With the file.exist command, R returns FALSE for the existence of the file. But after some research I found that the file link is stored in a directory below `~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs`and the file name is changed to `xxx.icloud` where xxx is the original file name.

Here's an example of the path to a a directory that holds a .icloud file from a shell in my mac

```
/Users/gcn/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/workspace/nutmod/data-raw/NutrientData
```

I can query for the existence of the file with `exists(xxx.icloud)`. But how do I tell my mac to download the iCloud file and then read it in? Using something like read.table or read.csv doesn't work because the pointer file is not csv.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a csv file directly from a iCloud folder on the Mac by using the path to that folder. Get the path by finding it in the finder. Then right click on the filename at the bottom of the finder window where it shows all the folders leading to the file and choose: Copy "YourFile" as Pathname.

That path will look something like this:

> "/Users/NAME/Library/Mobile
> Documents/com~apple~CloudDoc/Docs/YourFile.csv"

Use that in your read code:

```
iCloudDat <- read_csv("/Users/NAME/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/YourFileName.csv")
```

That should work.

Answer (score -1):

If the extension isn't *.txt* or *.csv* `read.table` and `read.csv` won't work.
you have to download the file and extract the tables to a readable format.

you can download the file using `download.file()` which is is the utils basic library.